# JWT authntication and its alternatives to reach RESTfulness of web application back-end

Tags: rest, session, authentication, cookies, jwt

In my company, we are building a web application and most actual problem is to pick an authentication solution. Im thinking about 3 of most used way to maintain 
session with authenticated user: stateless JWT (all session data holds JWT token in its payload), stateful JWT (token is only used to validate requests and in its payload it has session ID to session data record at server) and traditional session ID stored in cookie, which requires additional check for matching id in server.

Because i want to build this app RESTful, only first way seems right to me. This way a server does not need to hold any state.

My first question is: Is it ok, to store all session data in token payload (of course, those data are not that big and they are not supposed to be a secret, hence no security is needed).

Also, im going to implement logout logic as well and i know, that blacklisting tokens, which is in my case, i think, best solution ruines statelessness too. 
Do you know of any other way to implement logout logic which IMMEDIATELY invalidates JWT token ?

Thank you for your answers.

EDIT:
In case of invalidation, im thinking about sending an updated token with either a flag which tells "im invalidated token" or with expired expire date. This solution but works only for "good boy" users. Hackers will keep previous and still valid token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logout with JWT works by deleting the token client-side. Like this.

```
function removeToken() {
  localStorage.removeItem("jwt-token");
}
```

Without the token, the user is logged out. So I think it is immediate?

Comment: Ok, this works in case I'm in control of client-side code. 
Still, it's far away from being bulletproof. If client would want to, he could backup token and use it even after removal from local storage.

Comment: If you want to control the auth server-side maybe look into cookie-sessions. This is a great tutorial. (https://www.sitepoint.com/passport-authentication-for-nodejs-applications/)

Comment: Cookie-sessions looks like the traditional solution i mentioned. It makes server stateful, which is not that bad, i used this method before many times, but now i would like to try build fully RESTful back-end and this approach ruins it a little.